# change header bootstrap collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to have a different style for the panel header when it's open, so i created the class bold that is being added on element click. All good if i keep clicking on the same element, the item toggles correctly, problem is when i click on a different element: i want the class to be removed from the previous one:

```
$('.panel').on('click',function(){ 
$('.collapse').collapse('hide');
$('.collapse',this).collapse('show');
$('.panel-title',this).toggleClass('bold');
});
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e909Lndw/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best solution I'm sure but it works.

```
$('.panel').on('click',function(){ 
$('.collapse').collapse('hide');
$('.collapse',this).collapse('show');

$('.panel-title').removeClass('bold');
$('.panel-title',this).toggleClass('bold');

if($('[aria-expanded = "true"]',this).val() === undefined)
{
    $('.panel-title',this).removeClass('bold');
}

});
```